# How to 301 redirect with same url structures?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect site a to site b with same url structures. My htaccess is

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.siteb.com/

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ index.php?video=$1&id=$2&words=$3

RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)$ index.php?videos=$1
```

However, on the redirected site, it adds additional variables. For example;

siteA.com/y/T5INF08ZEdA/Miranda-Kerr-In-Hot-Water-with-Orlando-Bloom

siteB.com/y/T5INF08ZEdA/Miranda-Kerr-In-Hot-Water-with-Orlando-Bloom?video=y&id=T5INF08ZEdA&words=Miranda-Kerr-In-Hot-Water-with-Orlando-Bloom

What is the correct way to 301 redirect with same url structures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of the 2 main problems in your code:

1. Mixing of mod_alias and mod_rewrite rules.
2. Not using `L` flag in mod_rewrite rules and that is causing multiple rules firing on same URL.

I would suggest you to stick with mod_rewrite only and keep your .htaccess like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)sitea\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.siteb.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^videos/(.*)$ index.php?videos=$1 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(.*?)/?$ index.php?video=$1&id=$2&words=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: It doesnt redirect to siteb on the 3rd rewrite ruled pages.

Comment: Do you always want to redirect to siteb from sitea?